# MongoDB - Add new property to each object in an array property for each document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I have the following collection in MongoDB:

```
// document 1
{  
  elements:[
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
    },
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
    }
  ]
},
// document 2
{

  elements:[
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
    },
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update every element of `elements` collection of every document in the following way :

I want to add the `property3: true` to get:

```
// document 1
{  
  elements:[
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
      prop3:true -> added property
    },
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
      prop3:true -> added property
    }
  ]
},
// document 2
{

  elements:[
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
      prop3:true -> added property
    },
    {
      prop1:true,
      prop2:false,
      prop3:true -> added property
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use the positional operator but it only updated the first element of `elements` array of each document:

```
await db.collection('MyCollection').updateMany(
  {
    elements: { $exists: true },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'elements.$.property3': true,
    },
  }
)
```

I've tried to use the match, but it does not update anything:

```
await db.collection('MyCollection').updateMany(
  {
    elements: {
      $elemMatch: {
        prop1: {$exists:true},
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'prop3': false,
    },
  }
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) all positional operator for `elements.$[].property3`.

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  elements: {
    $exists: true
  },
  
},
{
  $set: {
    "elements.$[].property3": true
  },
  
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i5Itn6YgNkj)